# Oracle to Redshift trunc function

Tags: oracle, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

I am trying to transition from Oracle to redshift and got stuck with this function conversion. Can someone help me with this?:

Oracle:

`RESOLVED_DATE BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD'),'Y') AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')`

RedShift: ?

I am trying to get date from start of the year to the query run date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
select ...
where RESOLVED_DATE between date_trunc('year',current_timestamp) and current_timestamp;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, was just wondering if there is any other function apart from Current_timestamp? which can be used for Run date like the one that I have on my query.

Comment: what timestamp do you want?

Comment: So, for me to submit a job, I will have to give a run date. When the job gets submitted, the data would be fetched from start of the year to run date. If we give Current_timestamp I am afraid that it might not run.